# show uploaded files in gridview using php

Tags: php

i uploaded files into my server image folder.
after upload want to display the uploaded files as thumbnails in the grid view or anything(like windows explorer), also want to select multi files from grid view and download it.. any help to be appreciated.. im using php...

thank you so much...

Comment: Please elaborate. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a nice project. I wish you all the best with it. (In other words: You didn't ask any question. What are you having problems with? No idea where to even start? Are you in need of a tutorial for PHP or image uploading? Or do you have a more specific problem?)

Comment: How to create grid view in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some pointers to get you started:

1. Loop through the images and simply output them all, then use some CSS padding and width setting to get them into a grid. Alternatively, output them in a table, inserting a `</tr><tr>` every *n* loop iterations.
2. Add a checkbox input using some uniquely identifying value to each image to make it "selectable".
3. Use some Javascript to spice up the selection process and make it more "Explorer-like".

Try it and come back with more specific questions as you encounter them (after trying to solve them yourself first).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a PHP Photo Gallery instead. There is an awesome gallery [Plogger](http://www.plogger.org/) that you can use.

Otherwise, here are [more PHP galleries](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&&rls=en&q=php+image+photo+gallery).

Answer (score 0):

That would be a rather large project to undertake. Try a premade package like:

http://www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/filemanager/ (simple and free)

or

http://www.filerun.com/ (looks good, but requires license)

Answer (score 0):

with the help of `<table><tr><td>`... you can make a grid view and with using the php code collect all uploaded files into an array then show the file in the grid view by inserting php code in between. In that you can give check boxes and place php code in between to generate an array while user cliks each check box correspondin to that file a link should be passed to the array and then post the values on the download button clik, in the next step you can use the php zip function to ip these file in the array and send it to user as download link